# Click a button with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to make a bot, that clicks on a button on a web page. I have already done it with selenium, but it's very slow, and i need it to be fast. So i chose the requests library. I just wanted to ask: is there any way you can press a button with requests?
Website: https://manomokykla.lrt.lt/mokyklos/ (I am just testing on this website and not planning to bot it or anything) I just want to find out how to press the button, So i can use it in my future projects.

here is the button on the website:

[image]

the button's function:

```
function(event) 
{

  var school = $(this).data('school-id');
  var ip = $('input[name="ip-address"]').val();
  var current = $('div[data-mokyk-id="' + school + '"] strong').text();
  var getCokies = Cookies.get('balsuok');

  Cookies.set('balsuok', '1', {
    expires: 30
  });

  if (getCokies !== undefined && getCokies == '1') {

  } else {
    var formData = {
      'from': 'balsuok',
      'school': school,
      'ip': ip
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/wp-content/themes/ism-lrt-promo/ajax/balsuok.php',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true
      })
      // using the done promise callback
      .done(function(data) {
        if (data['success'] == true) {
          $('.popup-all-info-success').addClass('active');
          $('.popup-all-info').removeClass('active');

          setTimeout(function() {
            $('.open-counter').show();
            $('.action-line').removeClass('active');
            $('.action-line').remove();

            $('div[data-mokyk-id="' + school + '"] strong').html(parseInt(current) + 1);
            $('div[data-mokyk-select="' + school + '"] span').attr('data-number-length', parseInt(current) + 1);

            $('.line span').each(function(i, obj) {
              var currentNumber = $(this).data('number-length');

              var calculate = (currentNumber * 100) / getMaxNumber;

              $(this).css('width', calculate + '%');
            });
          }, 1000);
        }
      })

    .fail(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Params after Vote:
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: You could always check what requests get sent when you press the button, otherwise I would adwise using selenium instead.

Comment: Have you tried "translatin" the ajax request into python-requests and you don't understand why it does'nt work ? Or do you want to know if it's an appropriate approach ? Or do you want S.O. to do it for you ?

Comment: Also, do you care about the front-end (your browser) effects of the button press or the back-end (the site server and database) ?